# Computer graphics: how to draw this effect using computer programs?

Tags: opengl, graphics

I am wondering how to draw this effect using computer programs, either CPU or GPU?

[image]

Comment: using openGL, using Photoshop, using paint?

Comment: @BDillan, using CPU or GPU (OpenGL).

Comment: You'll probably have to clarify your question along with adding a few examples of things you tried in order to receive any help. You can always update your question. Welcome to stack overflow, recommended reading: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two lines there. What you want to do is to pick the closer line for each pixel, and calculate the distance to it. This will be your intensity at a given point. Furthermore do a fade to black as you approach the bottom of the image (use your pixel's y position to do this)

your lines seem to be at exactly at 25% and 75% on the x axis, therefore a pseudode looks like this:

```
for each pixel p: //p.x and p.y is normalized to the 0-1 range!
  intensity = ( 0.25 - min( abs(p.x-0.25) , abs(p.x-0.75) ) ) / 0.25; //intensity is normalized to 0-1 range
  intensity *= intensity; //distance squared
  intensity *= (1.0 - p.y); //Top of image is 0, bottom is 1
  display_intensity();
end
```

Depending on how you want to use this, you can create a texture on the CPU, or use a shader and calculate it in GLSL on the GPU.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, there are two parts. I just think the connection area between the parts has a different formula.

Comment: Yes probably that's the distance squared...so you may have to put intensity *= intensity; before applying the p.y fadeout. I Added it to the answer